# Collection class that doesn't allow null elements?

Tags: java, collections, null

I'm looking for a class from the Java Collection Framework that would not allow null elements.

Do you know one?

Comment: What should happen? If you just want to ignore list.add(null) I would make a subclass of your favourite implementation, overwrite add() and check for null value

Comment: Perhaps the better way to do it is to never insert nulls in the first place? Tolerating (and thus guarding against) nulls is usually a poor practice.

Comment: @leifg Don't just overwrite add but also addAll! Otherwise you may be in for an interesting surprise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementations (with the notable exception of [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)) don't accept `null`.

[`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a special-purpose `Set` implementation that doesn't allow `null` values.

Answer (score 47):

Use `Constraints`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Constraints;
...
Constraints.constrainedList(new ArrayList(), Constraints.notNull())
```

from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) for maximum flexibility.

**UPDATE:** Guava Constraints has been deprecated in [Release 15](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release15) - apparently without replacement.

**UPDATE 2:** As of now (Guava 19.0-rc2) [Constrains](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Constraints.java) is still there and not deprecated anymore. However, it's missing from the [Javadoc](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0-rc2/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html).

I'm afraid that the Javadoc is right as `MapConstraint` have been deprecated in [Release 19](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release19), too

Comment: +1 for your answer but I want to stick with Java Framework ;)

Comment: OK, then I can offer you e.g. `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet` from JDK. Or `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Boolean>())`.

Comment: Unfortunately `Constraints` is deprecated and scheduled for removal in Guava 16.0 :-(

Comment: That's sad. Funnily, `MapConstaints` are not.

Comment: `Constraints` is still there and it is no longer marked as deprecated. :-)

Answer (score 12):

There's a roundup of such collections [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/LivingWithNullHostileCollections).

Comment: For my future projects I'll definitively have a look at Guava ! +1

Answer (score 12):

[Apache Commons Framework - CollectionUtils.addIgnoreNull](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#addIgnoreNull-java.util.Collection-T-)

Adds to myList if myObj is not null.

`org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.addIgnoreNull(myList, myObj)`

Answer (score 4):

Using Google Guava Predicates (the answer from @Joachim Sauer is deprecated)

```
//list is the variable where we want to remove null elements
List nullRemovedList=Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list, Predicates.notNull()));

//Or convert to Immutable list
List nullRemovedList2=ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(list, Predicates.notNull()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable does not allow null keys or values.

Comment: my goodness, that's a blast from the past! It isn't even a `Collection`, never mind a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Start [here, the Collections API Page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).  Check out the "See Also" section.  Follow the links.  The decision to allow or disallow *null* is made by the implementing class; just follow the links in the various "See Also" sections to get to the implementing classes (for example, HashMap) then look at the insertion methods (generally a variation on add, push, or put) to see if that implementation permits *null*.