# Collection Implementation to Block null elements being added

Tags: java

The HashSet Set implementation allows the addition of null.  Is there any Collection implementation that will not allow null?  I know I can do a remove for the null on the HashSet, but I was wondering if I can restrict it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> testing = new HashSet<String>();
    testing.add(null);
    testing.add("test");

    for(String str : testing){

    }

  }


//TreeSet allows null as well
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<String> testing = new TreeSet<String>();
    testing.add(null);

    for(String str : testing){
      System.out.println("testing");
    }

  }
```

Comment: A `TreeSet` does not accept `null`.

Comment: Are you looking for any `Collection` or just `Set` implementation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a Set implementation

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis TreeSet allows nulls, see updated question.

Comment: It'll fail if you try to run it, with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did run it and its prints out testing

Comment: Every implementation for SET has different purposes and pros/cons. If your starting with HashSet it means you want a list of Unique Values. If you want a HashMap it means you want key/value pairs. And a TreeMap means you want your key/value pairs to be ordered by Key. Each Data Structure has a specific purpose.

Comment: What Java version are you using? [It fails for Java 7.](http://ideone.com/Gnqbty)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you are right. I also got NullPointerException while running the program using TreeSet.

Comment: It depends on java version

Comment: It shouldn't. The javadoc says it will throw a `NullPointerException`. Please double check your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if you only have one element and its null in a TreeSet and don't add anything to the TreeSet after it will not throw a NPE

Comment: @c12 How are you adding that first `null` element? You can't add a `null` to a `TreeSet`. The underlying `TreeMap` will try to compare the `key` to itself, throwing a `NullPointerException` when trying to invoke the `compareTo` method on a `null` reference.

Comment: @c12 [It seems you are correct.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) The `put` method `null` check is commented out. I would either upgrade or try the other collection types in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TreeSet` is appropriate for your requirement. Its `add(Object)` method javadoc states

> Throws:
>
> **NullPointerException** - if the specified element is null and this set
>   uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements

in both [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29) and [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29).

Also, if you are looking for `Collection` implementations (rather than `Set` implements), there are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997142/java-list-not-allowing-null-elements).

Comment: +1 This does cover the requirements about a set not accepting null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HashSet, but with that restriction for no null, you could also create a class extending HashSet.

**Example:**

```
public class HashSetNullLess<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    public boolean add(E e) {
            if(e==null)
            return false;  //Or throw unsupported exception message

            return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

This should pretty much take care of the problem as I checked the code of HashSet.java and even the constructors accepting collections lead to the `add` method via `addAll` in `AbstractCollection.java`

See:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (E e : c)
            if (add(e))
                modified = true;
        return modified;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SotiriosDelimanolis. I tried to run this code in JDK 7.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
        set.add(null);
        set.add("Test");
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

But got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

I think using your requirement will be fulfilled.

Comment: @c12 without adding any element still getting same exception. Check it carefully.

Comment: with jdk version 1.6?

Answer (score -1):

- Consider to wrap Hashtable class. It does not allow **nulls**, however it implements **Map** interface. You can do this in a way as HasSet wraps HashMap. Take into account Hashtable is synchronized.
- Use next, but it is a really implicit and could make code reading harder

  ```
      HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>() {
      @Override
      public boolean add(String s) {
          if(s == null)
              throw new NullPointerException();
          return super.add(s);
      }
  };
  ```
- Use TreeMap, but before actual using it add just one element, because it accepts null only as initial element