# How to make an Integer instance not nullable

Tags: java, list, integer, nullable

Is there a way to ensure an `Integer` variable not to be `null`?

I need to create a list of integer values, so I cannot use `int` type. I need to work with a `List<Integer>` but this will allow `null` values for elements...

Do I need to use some particular implementation of `List` or is there some way to set `Integer` not nullable?

**Note** I need a `List`, not a `Set`.

Comment: You can make a wrapper that would reject null values.

Comment: Why don't you create your own List class that forbid having a `null` value ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6997392/1553851

Comment: write your own Integer wrapper class

Comment: Obviously, we don't want to reinvent any wheels. However, not *all* wheels have been invented (or at least in your case, publicly implemented).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils this seems like a very common problem, so it's very strange that nothing exists to solve it without having to implement `MyInteger` class...

Comment: Seems like one of us should do the rest of us a favor then; huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the add method of a List and check whether the element is null.

```
new LinkedList<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e) {
        if(e == null)
            return false;
        return super.add(e);
    }
};
```

You may need to add this check to the other insertion Methods like add(int pos, E value) or set(int pos, E value).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is none. Simplest way is just to add a pre-check:

```
if (intVal != null) {
  list.add(intVal);
} else {
 // TODO: error handling
}
```

Anyway you'll have to handle an exception/return-value for your custom Data Structure, which doesn't allow NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete answers above. In case you are using java8 you can benefit from [Optional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Queue implementation, like LinkedBlockingQueue, many of them don't allow nulls.

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

I also recommend you to take a look at Lombok's NonNull annotation:

http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try, after populating the List, to filter out the null values using the [Google Guava](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) **Collections2.filter()** method:

```
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList.add(new Integer(2));
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(new Integer(2));
    myList.add(new Integer(2));
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(new Integer(2));

    myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections2.filter(myList, new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Integer integer) {
            return integer != null;
        }
    }));

    System.out.println(myList); //outputs [2, 2, 2, 2]
```