# Application crashing on using Bitmap in for loop

Tags: android, bitmap

```
for (int k = 0; k < file.length; k++) {
        Bitmap myBitmap= null;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file[k].getAbsolutePath());
        bitMap.add(myBitmap);

}
```

My App is crashing when i am using this code for storing all image in
 bitmap Arraylist, For lesser number of image it works fine, but for
 more then 30 images it crashing.

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you look here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29,

you'll find out that decodeFile can return `null`. 
Therefore, you should check `myBitmap` before using it

You'll find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997142/java-list-not-allowing-null-elements) interesting as well:

Answer (score 0):

`For lesser number of image it works fine, but for more then 30 images it crashing`

Sounds like you are getting out of memory.. Not a NPE as someone mentioned in his answere. Use smaller images and scale them up when needed. Would be my first suggest without seeing logcat. Hope it helps.